# How to list all channel_name in a group?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, consumer, channel

I saw how to get the list of all channel_name in a group in channels 2

but I use channels 3 (3.0.4)

Do you know how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your consumer you can user this:

```py
group_name = "groupname" # YOUR GROUP NAME
print(self.channel_layer.groups.get(group_name, {}).items())
```